# How to set drop case to a different font in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, drop-cap

I set my font in ConTeXt like this:

```
\starttypescript[serif]                         [garamond]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif]                   [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]               [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]             [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic]         [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[sans]                          [garamond]
    \definefontsynonym[Sans]                    [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBold]                [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SansItalic]              [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBoldItalic]          [file:~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[garamond]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [rm][serif][garamond][default]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [ss][sans][garamond][default]
    \definetypeface[garamond]                   [mm][math][modern][default]
\stoptypescript
```

I would like to use a different font, at ~/.fonts/11/EBGaramond-Initials.otf for the drop caps:

```
\starttext

\placeinitial
\input knuth

\stoptext
```

How can I get ConTeXt to change for that font just for the drop caps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a font via `style` is a quick way to do it:

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
%Adjust font size ad libitum
\definefont[myfont][dejavuserif at 50pt]
\starttext
\setupinitial[style=\myfont]
\placeinitial
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]